# Find lines inside rectangles (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of lines and rectangles. What I need to do is to remove all lines from the list that are "inside more than one rectangle". I know how to do it using loops. I am looking for an elegant solution using Linq in C#. Is it possible?

I am using Rectangle.HitTest(Line l) to check if the line is inside a rectangle.

Comment: Wha? Not sure what you're askin here?

Comment: Then show your code using loops so that we can avoid dublicate work.

Comment: Most of the things possible with loops can be done in a functional way using lambdas too. Whether that's more elegant or not is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `List<Line>` and an `IEnumerable<Rectangle>` already, you can use the [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method:

```
List<Line> lines = ...
IEnumerable<Rectange> rectangles = ...
lines.RemoveAll(x => rectangles.Where(r => r.HitTest(x)).Skip(1).Any());
```

Comment: I like yours better than the one I was about to suggest.

Comment: Skip is also removing lines that are inside only one rect.

Comment: @user2250447 It shouldn't. The `Skip` should ignore one rectangle, and the `Any` will cause it to drop out of the list if there are any more after that. `Skip(1).Any()` is equivalent `Count() > 1`, but stops evaluating count after 2.

Comment: Can I use it with the List<Rectangles> instead of IEnumerable with your statement?

Comment: @user2250447 Yes, `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, so anything that implements the interface can be used. `List<Rectange>` implements `IEnumerable<Rectange>` (as does `Rectange[]` and many other classes).